# Last insert id in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

laravel 5
How do I download the latest id added to the model?
It's simple, I have a form that sends data via post to:

```
route:
    Route::get('/insert/{data}', 'IdataController@ins');
    Route::post('/insert/{data}', 'IdataController@add_data');
controller:

    public function ins($data = 1){


        if($data == 1){
//display data
        }elseif($data == 2){
// this place I need last insert id

        }



    }
    public function add_data(Request $request, $data){

        if($data == 1){
            $r = $this->insert_my([
                'name'=>$request->name,
                'relationid'=>$request->relationid
            ]);
            return $r;
        }else($data ==2){
//next operations
}

    }
    private function insert_my($data){

        $r=  Insertmodel::create([
            'name'=>$data['name'],
            'relationid'=>$data['relationid']
        ]);

        return Redirect::to('insert/2');
    }
```

The best solution for me is to download last id from Model. But how to do it ?

id needs to get in this place:

```
elseif($data == 2){
    // this place I need last insert id

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

**update**

```
$data = Model::all()->last()->id;
```

or

```
$data = Model::orderby('created_at')->first();
```

then `$data->id`

Comment: not work, Do you have some other way?As the "latest" download the latest id? I try Insertmodel::latest('id') but it is big array and Insertmodel::latest('id')->id but it's not work

Comment: try `$id = Model::orderby('created_at')->first()->id` then use $id for your code

Comment: i updated the answer , try again i made a small mistake

Comment: Thankssssssss :)))))

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve it this way:

```
private function insert_my($data){

    $r=  Insertmodel::create([
        'name'=>$data['name'],
        'relationid'=>$data['relationid']
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('insert/2?id='. $r->id);
}
```

Once you redirect, it will be available in the controller as `$request->id`.

Comment: but it is not safe. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: The question was how to get and pass the last inserted id.